# c++ why empty my map<string, string> if I use reference?

Tags: c++, reference

Here is my code. My map will be empty if I use reference for ELEM struct, otherwise i get correct value:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stack>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct ELEM;

struct ELEM {
    map<string, ELEM> Children;
    map<string, string> Attributes;
};

int main() {

    stack<ELEM> elements;
    ELEM root;
    elements.push(root);

    ELEM elem1;
    elements.push(elem1);
    elements.top().Attributes["attr1"] = "val1";
    elements.top().Attributes["attr2"] = "val2";

    ELEM &elem2 = elements.top(); // here is the problem ???
    elements.pop();
    elements.top().Children["child1"] = elem2;

    cout << elements.top().Children["child1"].Attributes.size() << endl;
    // i get '0'

    return 0;
}
```

Can you explain me, what is the problem?
Thanks

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2015

Comment: You poppe'd the element which is now destroyed and you have a dangling reference.

Comment: If you want to pin the element you have to make elem2 `const ELEM &`. Bacause it dissaperas otherwise. You are getting rvalue that is destroyed after `pop`

Comment: @AA That is *catastrophically* bad advice.  `const` means they you can't change the object via the reference `elem2`.  It does not mean it will be preservered.  Are you thinking of the case that you can initialize a const reference with a temporary, in which case the lifetime of the temporary will be extended?  Doesn't apply in this case - `top` returns a reference, not a temporary.

Comment: "const ELEM &" wrong. I lose inner structure also...
"ELEM elem2 = elements.top();"  is working, but it is copy(?), there is a something elegant way?

Comment: I dont think the code is doing what you think it is doing. Add a copy ctor to your code with a cout to find out what is exactly happening. When you do a push it creates a temporary, copies everything to that temporary and pushes it to the stack. If you want the same object push a pointer.

Comment: @MartinBonner, right the problem is top and pop, after pop the old ref is bad.

Comment: @barnus : the elegant solution is std::move

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `&`:

```
ELEM &elem2 = elements.top();
elements.pop();
```

`elem2` is a reference to `elem1`. In the second line calling `pop()` removes `elem1` from the stack and destroys it, making `elem2` and dangling reference. Calling `elem2.Attributes.size()` <s>returns `0`, since `elem2` refers to `elem1`, which has been destroyed.</s> happens to have returned `0` for you, but the behaviour is undefined — there's no guarantee what will happen (thanks to Caleth for pointing this out).

Without the `&`:

```
ELEM elem2 = elements.top();
elements.pop();
```

`elem2` is a copy of `elem1`, i.e. it is a new `ELEM` instance, whose values have been set to the same values as `elem1`. Calling `pop()` removes `elem1` from the stack and destroys it, same as before, but `elem2` still exists. Calling `elem2.Attributes.size()` returns `2`, since `elem2` is a copy of the (now destroyed) `elem1`.

Comment: "Calling elem2.Attributes.size() returns 0", because that is consistent with undefined behaviour. There is no guarantee of what *any* part of the first example does.

Comment: @Caleth Yes, of course, that makes much more sense. Thanks for pointing that out, will edit now.

Comment: Thanks! Than "HRML node = std::move(elements.top());" is efficient and elegant solution?

Comment: Yes, I think so. See, for example, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37173771/8951763).