# why this reference set not allowed?

Tags: c++

New to C++, I thought if I define a container and specify its type inside as `string`, then it should come out of `string` without fuss, and I want to have a reference variable alias to this string. Obviously, I missed something here, as compiler complains it can not convert void to string. Can someone help clarify? thanks.

```
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::queue<std::string> myqueue;

    myqueue.push("val1");
    myqueue.push("val2");

    while (!myqueue.empty()) {
        std::string & s = myqueue.pop();
        std::cout << s << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use myqueue.front() and then .pop().
pop() does not return anything

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/pop

Answer (score 4):

That's because `std::queue::pop` is not returning anything (void).

If you wanted to acces the first element and then remove it, you should use `std::queue::front` and then  `std::queue::pop`.

```
while (!myqueue.empty()) {
  std::string & s = myqueue.front();
  std::cout << s << endl;
  myqueue.pop();
}
```

I moved `myqueue.pop();` after `std::cout << s << endl;` to avoid dangling reference (reference to an object that no longer exists).

Comment: @arorias \*whispers\* `queue::front`, not `queue::back` \*whispers\*

Comment: my bad, now it should be okay :)

Answer (score 3):

`queue::pop` has return type of `void` and merely removes first element. If you want to retain its value, then first retrieve it with `front()` and you should keep it by value rather than by reference, as the moment it's popped, reference to it becomes dangling.

```
std::string next{myqueue.front()};
myqueue.pop();
```

Answer (score 1):

[`std::queue::pop()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/pop) does not return anything. It just removes the first element of the queue. You have to use [`std::queue::front()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/front) to get a reference to the first element (and store it in `s`) then call `std::queue::pop()` to remove the first element from the queue **after** you have used `s` and you don't need it any more.

It is important to not use the reference stored in `s` after you call `std::queue::pop()` because, behind the scenes, `std::queue` wraps a `std::dequeue` object and `std::queue::pop()` calls [`std::dequeue::pop_first()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/pop_front) on it. The documentation page of `std::dequeue::pop_first()` states:

> Iterators and references to the erased element are invalidated.

Your code could be:

```
while (!myqueue.empty()) {
    // get a reference to the first element of the queue
    std::string & s = myqueue.front();
    // use it to handle the element
    std::cout << s << endl;
    // remove the first element of the queue; this invalidates all references to it
    myqueue.pop();
    // the reference stored in `s` is invalid now; don't use it any more
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Moving the element from the queue and immediately invoking `pop()`

As you are consuming the elements of the queue, rather than:

- Storing a reference to an element you are about to `pop()` from the queue, or
- Copying the element from the `front()` to avoid a dangling reference scenario,

you could *move* the `front()` element out of the queue and immediately invoke `pop()` on the queue. E.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
T removeFrontFromOfQueue(std::queue<T>& q) {
    T front = std::move(q.front());
    q.pop();
    return front;  // Should be able to rely on NRVO, and if not, a move ctor.
}

int main() {
    std::queue<std::string> myqueue({"val1", "val2"});

    while (!myqueue.empty()) {
        std::string s = removeFrontFromOfQueue(myqueue);
        std::cout << s << " ";
    }  // val1 val2
}
```

As is covered in the following Q&A:

- [Is it okay to "Move" an object from a queue, if you're about to pop from it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37173697/is-it-okay-to-move-an-object-from-a-queue-if-youre-about-to-pop-from-it),

this is safe.

---

#### Limit the lifetime of the reference to the `front()` object

Alternatively, if you choose to store a reference to the `front()` of the queue, consider limiting the lifetime of the reference to before invoking `pop()` on the queue. E.g.:

```
while (!myqueue.empty()) {
    {
        const std::string& s = myqueue.front();
        std::cout << s << " ";
    }
    myqueue.pop();
} // val1 val2
```